# return value of an updated field in mysqli

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli, sql-update

Is it possible after update, return value of an updated field?

```
public function plusfiled()
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE table SET rand = rand + 1 where id=4";

        if (($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)) 
        {
            return 'rand';
        }

    }
```

Comment: Yes, you can return the variable value.  You'll probably want to return an error or something in the case when the update was not successful.  But you wouldn't have quotes around 'rand' if you want the variable value.  Return 'rand' will return the string 'rand'.  You probably want the variable $rand

Comment: No I want value of new 'rand'. how can do it?(without call another select)

Comment: Ok, in that case you'll have to query the database and get the new value.

Comment: @devlin carnate  thanks

Comment: So this is this not an issue anymore? (cc: @devlincarnate)

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the update in a stored procedure, and return the value as an `out` parameter.  The body would look something like:

```
update table
    set rand = (out_rand := rand + 1)
    where id = in_id;
```